# C pointer data structure in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'd like to see what an actual pointer variable contains in memory. I know it contains an address. But what else does it contain?

In *C Programming Language*, by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie on page 93 it says that a pointer is 2 or 4 bytes. There is a helpful graphic on this page.

A graphic and data definition helps.

Comment: It's implementation dependent, but on most conventional computers it's just an address.

Comment: It's just an (unsigned) integer on most systems

Comment: That book is somewhat dated. On modern systems it's either 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: What are those 4 or 8 bytes?

Comment: It says it's a common implementation on all systems.

Comment: @JoshGinn It is the memory address of where the data are actually stored

Comment: @JoshGinn, that integer is 4 or 8 bytes wide. In other words, 4 or 8 bytes are needed to hold any possible address the computer can work with

Comment: That's it? Or is there something else?

Comment: Ok, Thanks @ForceBru, I wanted a definition of how wide a memory address is.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is the same for a pointer to heap memory? I thought the size of a `malloc()` or `calloc()` operation was stored somewhere so `free()` knows how much memory to reclaim.

Comment: You're asking another implementation specific answer without specifying an implementation. Which compiler's `malloc` on what system?

Comment: Re "*I wanted a definition of how wide a memory address is.*", A pointer is `sizeof(void*)` bytes in size

Comment: *"I wanted a definition of how wide a memory address is."* Also (generally) the same width as the native processor register stize. (e.g. x86 - 32-bit/4-byte, x86_64 - 64-bit/8byte)

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline - *"A pointer is a pointer is a pointer...."* It does not depend on the metadata scheme used by `malloc/calloc/free` to identify allocated regions when moving the break (e.g. `sbrk` -- though most implementation now use `mmap` when allocating)

Comment: Where is the metadata stored for a pointer when using malloc/calloc/free?

Comment: @JoshGinn Wherever the implementation wants to store it. It may have a separate data structure just to keep the sizes of allocated blocks. It may add some extra bytes to the beginning of the block and store the length there. It can do it some other way if it wants to.

Answer (score 3):

*If* the processor uses a "flat", byte-addressed memory addressing scheme, where the address space is modeled as N bytes of memory, individually numbered from 0 to N-1, then in the usual case a pointer value is simply the number, or "address", of the individual byte of memory that the pointer points to.

If you think of memory as being one big, huge array of `unsigned char`, then a pointer is literally an index into that array.  (Normally, when we compare and contrast arrays and pointers, we think of array indices and pointers as being two very different things, but they're actually pretty closely related, not just in computer programming but in the English language, as you'll realize if you think about the name of the finger you use to point at things with.)

I started out this answer with a big `if`, because none of this is guaranteed.  It's not the sort of thing you're supposed to depend on if you're interested in portable programming.  There are machines which have word-addressed instead of byte-addressed memory spaces, or which use something other than a "flat" scheme.  But those have mostly died out, and for better or worse, the vast majority of programmers today will encounter nothing but the flat, byte-addressed ones.

With that said, though, there are also implementations which use "smart" pointers, which are larger, fancier data structures that carry (for example) bounds information along with them.  Those are absolutely not ruled out by the C pointer model.